# При выводе данных в таблице в jsp, шапка таблицы выводится, а сами данные нет

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, веб-сервер

```
Передача списка в jsp:

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class EmployeeControllers {
@Autowired
ServiceEmployee serviceEmployee;

@GetMapping("/employees")
public String getUserList(Model model) {

    List<Employee> list = serviceEmployee.getAll();
    model.addAttribute("employees",list);
    return "employeesList";
}
```

Jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ListForEmployees</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Employees List</h2>
<c:if  test="${employees != null}">
    <table  class="grid" style="width: 850px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                 <th>ID</th>
                 <th>First Name</th>
                 <th >Last Name</th>

            </tr>
       </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach  var="employee" items="${employees}">
        <tr>
            <td> ${employee.id} </td>
            <td> ${employee.firstName} </td>
            <td> ${employee.lastName} </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

`c:forEach` входит в стандартную библиотеку тегов JSP(JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library, она же **JSTL**).

Проверьте в pom.xml наличие зависимости:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Если зависимость отсутствует - добавьте.

Подключите JSTL core на странице:
Для этого в начало jsp добавьте

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

В результате должно получится так:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ListForEmployees</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Employees List</h2>
<c:if  test="${employees != null}">
    <table  class="grid" style="width: 850px;">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th >Last Name</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach  var="employee" items="${employees}">
            <tr>
                <td> ${employee.id} </td>
                <td> ${employee.firstName} </td>
                <td> ${employee.lastName} </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: всё это и так на месте, но увы таблица не выводится((

Comment: @КонстантинВолосян, тогда можете скинуть ссылку на гитхаб с кодом данного проекта, чтобы я мог посмотреть что в нем не так, потому что кода, приведенного в вопросе мне недостаточно для понимания того что у вас случилось. самую очевидную мысль я высказал.